# Whitespace in Windows PowerShell variables can't proceed

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
$HPLOCONS = "C:\Users\i\OneDrive - A\Documents\A\ILOstuffs\HPLOCONS.exe"
$FilePath = "C:\Users\i\OneDrive - A\Documents\A\ILOstuffs\ilo.txt"
$iLOUser = "uid"
$iLOPass = "PW"

$iLOs = Get-Content $FilePath;
echo "Number of iLOs ="$iLOs.Count;
echo $iLOs | Out-GridView

foreach ($iLO in $iLOs) {
    Invoke-Expression "$HPLOCONS -name $iLOUser -password $iLOPass -addr $iLO"
}
```

Since I moved to OneDrive it is not possible to handle the space in the `$HPLOCONS` and `$Filepath`. It is complaining about the space.
How can I escape it? I tried many way but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`Invoke-Expression` IS EVIL. DO NOT USE IT.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)**

Use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) instead:

```
& $HPLOCONS -name $iLOUser -password $iLOPass -addr $iLO
```